# Fitting a slopes-as-outcomes linear mixed model using lme4

Tags: multilevel-analysis, random-effects-model, lme4-nlme

In education research there is a type of multilevel model referred to as a slopes-as-outcomes model by [Raudenbush and Bryk (2002)](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1848728468). Raudenbush and Bryk's HLM software uses its own notation in describing multilevel models, but it is often easy to convert into `lme4` notation. The slopes-as-outcomes model they describe however, does not seem to have any easy analog. Model 4 [at this link](http://www.ats.ucla.edu/stat/hlm/seminars/hlm6/mlm_hlm6_seminar.htm) shows a worked example using the HLM software. This example fits the following model:

$$
MATHACH_{ij} =  β_{0j} + β_{1j} SES + r_{ij}
$$

$$
β_{0j} =  γ_{00}  + γ_{01}(SCHTYPE) + γ_{02}(MEANSES) + u_{0j}
$$

$$
β_{1j} =  γ_{10}  + γ_{11}(SCHTYPE) + γ_{12}(MEANSES) + u_{1j}
$$

This model is saying that for each school `j` both an intercept term $B_{0j}$ and a slope for socioeconomic status (SES) $B_{1j}$ is estimated. However, both $B_{0j}$ and $B_{1j}$ are predicted by the variables `MEANSES` and school type (`SCHTYPE`).

In `lme4` I would attempt to fit this model by using the following command:

```
library(lme4)
mod1 <- lmer(MATHACH ~ SES + MEANSES + SCHTYPE + (1 + SES | SCH)
```

In R I know this will return coefficients for `SES`, `MEANSES`, and `SCHTYPE` as fixed effects, and an intercept and `SES` slope for each school as part of the random effects. I also know that the slope and intercept for the schools are estimated *conditional* on the effects of `SCHTYPE` and `MEANSES`.

In HLM however, the reported outputs are different. As the example I linked to shows, HLM reports **2** coefficients for `MEANSES` and `SCHTYPE` -- one each for the effect on the $j$ intercepts and $j$ `SES` slopes. So instead of an output where the call to `fixef(mod1)` looks like this:

```
fixef(fm1)
(Intercept)        SCHTYPE    MEANSES
251.40510         10.46729    9.7734
```

It would look like this:

```
fixef(fm1)
-- Intercepts --
(Intercept)        SCHTYPE    MEANSES
 251.410           10.49      9.74
-- Slope SES --
(Intercept)        SCHTYPE    MEANSES
  232.40            4.49      8.34
```

I am not sure how HLM derives these estimates. I am wondering if there is a way within `lme4` to partial out the effect of a predictor like `SCHTYPE` between the random intercepts and the random slopes. Or if HLM is simply doing some post-estimation regression of `SCHTYPE` and `MEANSES` on the BLUPS for the slopes and intercepts and reporting those coefficients alongside the general results for the model.

I'd like to replicate this type of analysis but in R to take advantage of R's superior handling of missing data and binomial responses.

[This question has previously been raised](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/115746/correct-specification-of-hlm-in-lmer), and the model form suggested was this:

```
lmer(mathach ~ sector + meanses + ses + sector:ses + meanses:ses + 
(1+ses|school),data=dat)
```

However, I'm not sure that using this model one could interpret the `sector:ses` interaction term as the prediction of the effect of `sector` on the *school-level* `ses` slopes. For the analysis I would like to do I'm interested in assessing the magnitude and direction of the impact of school-level indicators on the school intercept and slope estimates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may be a late answer but I will try to answer it however. In pages 117-130 of [Raudenbush and Bryk (2002)](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1848728468), as you rightly mentioned, the slope as outcome model has been represented as

$$
MATHACH_{ij} =  β_{0j} + β_{1j} SES + r_{ij}
$$

$$
β_{0j} =  γ_{00}  + γ_{01}(SCHTYPE) + γ_{02}(MEANSES) + u_{0j}
$$

$$
β_{1j} =  γ_{10}  + γ_{11}(SCHTYPE) + γ_{12}(MEANSES) + u_{1j}
$$

This translates to a a 2 level HLM model that can be written in lmer as

```
lmer(mathach ~ sector + meanses + ses + sector:ses + meanses:ses + ...
```

The authors explain the significant coefficients in Page 128 which are nothing but the interaction effects coefficients.

I came across a [webpage](http://www.columbia.edu/~cjd11/charles_dimaggio/DIRE/styled-4/styled-11/code-9/) that describes Bayesian meta-regression where they model the slopes of the hierarchical model, which is what you had in mind perhaps.